# Does rdmsr timing depend on the register read?

Tags: performance, x86, x86-64, intel

Does the time required to execute an [`rdmsr`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdmsr) depend significantly on the register read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the time can depend significantly on the register. Here are a few examples (as measured on an Intel Core i7-8700K):

- Reading register E8H *(IA32_APERF)* requires about 91 core cycles.
- Reading register 1A0 *(IA32_MISC_ENABLE)* typically requires between ~500 and ~550 core cycles.
- Reading register 19CH *(IA32_THERM_STATUS)* typically requires between ~900 and ~1050 core cycles.
- Reading register 198H *(IA32_PERF_STATUS)* typically requires between ~5300 and ~5700 core cycles.

Here are the [nanoBench](https://github.com/andreas-abel/nanoBench) commands I used for the measurements:

```
sudo ./kernel-nanoBench.sh -asm "rdmsr" -asm_init "mov RCX, 0xE8"    
sudo ./kernel-nanoBench.sh -asm "rdmsr" -asm_init "mov RCX, 0x1A0"
sudo ./kernel-nanoBench.sh -asm "rdmsr" -asm_init "mov RCX, 0x19C"
sudo ./kernel-nanoBench.sh -asm "rdmsr" -asm_init "mov RCX, 0x198"
```

Comment: Thanks for the epic answer. I was specifically interested in 0x198 MSR_PERF_STATUS, and indeed this one is really slow: `Core cycles: 3577.96` using `nanoBench`. I get similar timings to you for the other MRS, on an i7-6700HQ.

Comment: This one is even slower on the Core i7-8700K. I added it to the answer.